# MAUI on Android : listing folder contents of an SD Card and writing in it

Tags: c#, android, maui

I've been trying to listing folder contents of an SD Card and write in it in my Android phone using MAUI.

My target is to access a folder (namely : SD card/DCIM/Test EXIF, list its contents and modify/delete file metadata in a batch.

I've been trying for days to no avail, I cannot access the SD Card and have no clues on how to do it.
I tried a simple file picker like this :

```
var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync();
if (result != null)
{
     // Do Stuff
}
```

The access to the SD Card works but that's not what I want : the file is apparently copied in the cache, and I want the original file to be editable. And I want multiple files to be process, not one by one.

I tried another approach : with GetLogicalDrives()

```
   string folders = "";
   var xxx = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

   foreach (string foldnm in xxx)
       folders = folders + foldnm + ";";
```

And in the list, I found "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data" which seems to be the base of the one I'm looking for. So I tried the following :

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data", "*");
```

But I have an access denied : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data' is denied.'. I thought it was a Right Issue, so in Android/Resources.AndroidManifest.xml I added the following lines :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Uninstalled / Reinstalled the app and got the same result, so I added in the code a prompt to check and request the read (for now) permission, but the grant prompt never appears :

```
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Permission Denied", "OK");
            // Ask for permission
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        }

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data", "*");
        }
```

On my device's Settings > Apps > App Info > My App > Permissions : no permission is listed at all.

Any clues ? I'm pulling the rest of my hair out for some days now !

Maybe I'm wrong in my approach, but I'm trying to read/write to my external storage in Android

EDIT :
My path was wrong. The address of my SD Card is /storage/3439-3532/.
I can list its directories successfully but when trying to access the files, I have an access denied error :

```
string[] dirs1 = Directory.GetDirectories("/storage/3439-3532/", "*"); // works OK
string[] dirs2 = Directory.GetDirectories("/storage/3439-3532/BEB/", "*"); // works OK
string[] theFiles = Directory.GetFiles("/storage/3439-3532/BEB/", "*"); // KO !
```

Comment: https://github.com/papnak/SafMaui

Comment: Thanks Jason. I took a look at the SafMaui repo. It's working but allows me to select only one file, just like the FilePicker I used at first. I can't get my head around it, as I'm unable to list the files present in the directory.

Comment: your question explicitly mentions "read/write", not "list the contents of the folder"

Comment: indeed, sorry. I changed the question title, I thought its content was explicit enough

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+list+sd+card+contents+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. I have to implement the rights differently :
In my Android Manifest, just the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was needed :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In my Android >MainActivity.cs, I added a new intent. At the first app launch, it'll ask for the permission :

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    // Added this v
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission);
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", this.PackageName, null);
            intent.SetData(uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Now I can list the files I want, create new directories, new file, etc...

```
string[] theFiles = Directory.GetFiles("/storage/3439-3532/DCIM/Camera", "*");

Directory.CreateDirectory("/storage/3439-3532/BEB");

using FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite("/storage/3439-3532/BEB/test.txt");
using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
await streamWriter.WriteAsync("OKAY");
```

I still find the hardcoded part of the /storage/thingy/ ugly, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [How to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android permission with MAUI?](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/6004)

Comment: I wasn't able to implement this. This is weird : I managed to get the list of directories quickly using Directory.GetDirectories("/storage/3439-3532/", "*").

However, trying to get the directory's Files with Directory.GetFiles("/storage/3439-3532/DCIM", "*") get me a Access Denied error. Trying to create a new directory with Directory.CreateDirectory("/storage/3439-3532/BEB"); too.